# Filter an array for even strings

Tags: arrays, string

I want the function to return strings of equal length, which it does but I also want it to remove non-strings and strings of odd length. Can anyone help?

```
 function evenLength(items) {
 let evenNumber = items.filter(items => {
 if(items % 2 != 0){
 return true;
 }
 });
 return(evenNumber)
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to check for parity and check if the array element is a string you can do the following:

```
function checkForParityAndStringType(data) {

    var result = [];

    for (let i = 0;i  < data.length; i++) {
        const elem  = data[i];
        
        // remove non string
        if (typeof elem !== 'string') continue;
        
        // Length is not even
        if (elem.length % 2 !== 0) continue;

        result.push(elem)
    };
    
    return result
}
```